# Select multiple sections of rows by index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have large DataFrame with GPS path and some attributes. A few sections of the path are those which I need to analyse. I would like to subset only those sections to a new DataFrame. I can subset one section at the time but the idea is to have them all and to have an original index.

The problem is similar to:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'B':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']},
                  index=range(10,20,))
```

I want o get something like:

```
cdf = df.loc[[11:13] & [17:20]] # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

desired outcome:

```
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
13  3  d
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```

I know the example is easy with `cdf = df.loc[[11,12,13,17,18,19],:]` but in the original problem I have thousands of lines and some entries already removed, so listing points is rather not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
cdf = pd.concat([df.loc[11:13], df.loc[17:20]])
print (cdf)
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
13  3  d
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```

Another solution with `range`:

```
cdf = df.loc[list(range(11,14)) + list(range(17,20))]
print (cdf)
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
13  3  d
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate the slices:

```
In [16]: df.loc[np.r_[11:13, 17:20]]
Out[16]: 
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```

Note, however, that 
`df.loc[A:B]` selects labels `A` through `B` with `B` included. 
`np.r_[A:B]` returns an array of `A` through `B` with `B` excluded. To include `B` you would need to use `np.r_[A:B+1]`.

When passed a slice, such as `df.loc[A:B]`, `df.loc` ignores labels that are not in `df.index`.  In contrast, when passed an array, such as `df.loc[np.r_[A:B]]`, `df.loc` may add a new row filled with NaNs for each value in the array which is not in `df.index`.

Thus to produce the desired result, you would need to adjust the right endpoint of the slices and use `isin` to test for membership in `df.index`:

```
In [26]: df.loc[df.index.isin(np.r_[11:14, 17:21])]
Out[26]: 
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
13  3  d
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [select_rows](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_rows) - note that the selection is based on the label, not the integer position:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd

df.select_rows(slice(11,13), slice(17,20))
    A  B
11  1  b
12  2  c
13  3  d
17  7  h
18  8  i
19  9  j
```